# How to apply field masking to suitecrm fields?

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

There was a module for sugar crm but it does not work on my installation of suitecrm event though it installs fine. https://www.sugaroutfitters.com/support/SynoFieldMask

After saving my masks I can find the dependency-php-files in the Accounts module, but I can still enter whatever I want into the fields.

One of these php files at custom/Extension/modules/Accounts/Ext/Dependencies looks like :

```
<?php
$dependencies["Accounts"]["phone_office_synofieldmask"] =
array (
  'hooks' =>
  array (
    0 => 'edit',
  ),
  'trigger' => 'true',
  'triggerFields' =>
  array (
    0 => 'phone_office',
  ),
  'onload' => true,
  'actions' =>
  array (
    0 =>
    array (
      'name' => 'SetSynoFieldMask',
      'params' =>
      array (
        'target' => 'phone_office',
        'label' => 'phone_office_label',
        'value' =>
        array (
          'mask' => '+9[9[9]](9[9[9]])999[9]-9999 ',
          'greedy' => false,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
?>
```

I researched looking at these:

https://www.sugaroutfitters.com/support/SynoFieldMask/1069
https://www.sugaroutfitters.com/support/SynoFieldMask/753

My version Version 7.7.9
Sugar Version 6.5.24 (Build 509). The masking just never appears and it lets me enter anything.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the plugin supports SugarCRM 7.2.0 to 7.8.0.0.

SuiteCRM is based on SugarCRM CE version 6.5.24. Additionally it seems like the CE version of SugarCRM isn't supported by the plugin either.

Comment: Thanks Jim. Maybe some weekend (or two) I can write one for Suite. Thanks again for your feedback and personal note. Truly appreciate it.